# Importing libraries and being recognised in PyCharm

Tags: python, installation, module, openpyxl

Apologies if this has been asked before. I have searched this site for an answer but it fails to address my problem.
I am trying to install a module - openpyxl- in my PyCharm application.
Although it shows as being installed, it fails to load into PyCharm and I get a run time error highlighting this problem.

I have downloaded the openpyxl module, added it to the interpreter (shown in the screenshot), restarted the program but still get the same error.
I understand the PATH may be incorrect but I'm unsure as to how it can be corrected. Any help would be gratefully received - thank you.

Comment: There is no screen shot or error message. We also prefer text as text, so don't post images of code, errors, logs or other text. See [ask]. PATH has nothing to do with how Python imports; it has its own PYTHON_PATH, but I'd try not to mess with that. Either way, this question needs more details.

Comment: @Robert I guess it's `PYTHONPATH` not `PYTHON_PATH` and there are reasons to change it sometimes

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yes, could be, thanks. While there are reasons to change it, these are usually not reasons related to not being able to install a module.

Comment: @Robert, yes, but it seems like he has importing problems, which `PYTHONPATH` can be reason of. Although most likely the reason is 2 different environments or something like that

Answer (score 0):

All sorted.
The module was showing as being imported but wouldn't be seen in the program, hence the error.
All I did was check in the PyCharm ==> preferences ==> Interpreter box, click on the 'update' arrow and then the module loaded with no problem.

Thanks for your help; noted about the screenshot (it did load originally).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).